# My static blocks are not displaying correctly anymore

Tags: magento-1.9

My static blocks are not displaying within my widget correctly anymore.  They use to display nicely from top to bottom, but now are displaying horizontally instead of vertically.  Basically, I have a widget named "Main Top", and I was displaying 4 static blocks within that widget.  Now if I only display one block within that widget all is fine, but as soon as I add more than one, boom its horizontal placement again.  Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: ok I actually figured it out.  Some how the layout on large devices got messed up.  So i just scrolled each block over to fit 12, and now it is displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drag each block over until it reads "12" instead of "4"